# simplecart successful payment

Tags: javascript, simplecart

Does it mean the transaction is verified of valid if the simple cart checkout is successful?

checkout: {
 type: 'PayPal' , 
email: 'myemail', 
success: 'success.html' ,
sandbox: true
}

Answer (score 0):

```
success: 'success.html'
```

This is the 'Return Url' that users will be presented with after they have completed the checkout with Paypal.

You would typically have it linked to a 'thankyou' page or something similar back on your website. If you are looking to keep track of verified payments/users, then you should look into IPN and how that works. https://www.paypal.com/ipn